# Unable to install Ubuntu on M.2 drive

Tags: partitioning, 20.04, ssd, ext4, nvme

I have Secure Boot and CSM disabled, Windows Features(?) set to Other OS, and UEFI related settings to UEFI Only. I have nothing else installed other than Ubuntu 20.04 on another drive which is HDD and disconnected. I tried creating a GPT partition table first before proceeding to create an efi and ext4 partitions using gparted. I tried doing it using disk utility. I tried letting the installer do it by erasing everything. The end result is the same -- it can't create an ext4 partition. I grabbed the error from disk utility:

[image]

My drive is kingmax PCIe SSD 512GB. I suppose it's because of this particular brand but I assumed that Linux, by now, is compatible with almost all M.2 SSD out there. Windows runs okay on it. Is there any way I can get around this?

**UPDATE**

Some more hardware details:
Motherboard: Gigabyte H170M-D3H-CF
RAM: Kingston 16GB DDR4 2133MT/s
CPU: Intel Core i5 @ 3.2GHz x 4

Comment: Is this computer a Dell, by any chance?

Comment: Nope. I assembled this myself.

Comment: No worries. I've seen some Dell Precision desktops require that Kingmax NVMe disks be set in RAID rather than ACPI mode (even if there's just one storage device), which is why I asked. If this is a custom build, then it might help to include some of the hardware details in your question so that someone might be able to offer some specific suggestions 

Comment: Okay, I'll add it. I've read that as well but didn't know the disks were Kingmax. Would RAID make my HDD unusable? Would I still be able to access it?

Comment: @adredx I think is what Matigo meant was using the drive in AHCI mode instead of RAID.  And yes, using in RAID mode can make it so Ubuntu will not install on the drive correctly.

Comment: So I recently tried Fedora 34 with Btrfs, it installed flawlessly. It seems ext4 is the issue cos Fedora34+ext4 didn't work as well.